# Varnish breaks Wordpress visual editor TinyMCE

Tags: wordpress, apache, tinymce, varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm currently running mutliple Wordpress 4 installs with a Varnish 3 + Apache 2.22 + PHP 5.4 stack, and it turns out that Varnish seems to break Wordpress WYSIWYG, TinyMCE.
Therefore I can only use the "Text" editor.

I know it sounds weird that a reverse-proxy breaks a WYSIWYG inside a backoffice, but if I stop Varnish to have a classic LAMP stack anew, everything gets back in order. So it must be something about a cookie being stripped, or something like that.

Here is Varnish's VCL (a bit messy I'll give you that):

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80";
    .first_byte_timeout = 300s;
}

# This function is used when a request is sent by a HTTP client (Browser)
sub vcl_recv {

    if (req.backend.healthy) {
        set req.grace = 1m;
    } else {
        set req.grace = 1d;
    }

    if (req.http.host ~ "(THE.IP.ADRESS.OF.THE.SERVER)") {
        return (pass);
    }
    else {
        set req.backend = default;
    } 

    # Uniformisation des User agent
    if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "MSIE") {
        set req.http.User-Agent = "msie";
    } else {
        set req.http.User-Agent = "firefox";
    }

    # Display client's IP instead of Varnish's in Apache logs
    if (req.restarts == 0) {
        if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
        }
    }

    # Normalize the header, remove the port (in case you're testing this on various TCP ports)
    set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");

    # Post requests will not be cached
    if (req.request == "POST") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # BAN tuto
    if (req.request == "BANURL") {
        ban("obj.http.x-host == " + req.http.host + " && obj.http.x-url ~ " + req.url);
        error 200 "Ban added for host " + req.http.host + " and URL " + req.url;
    }

    # Blitz hack
    if (req.url ~ "/mu-.*") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Joomla back 
    if(req.url ~ "^/administrator" || req.url ~ "^/component/banners") {    
        return (pass);
    }

    #Wordpress back
    if(req.url ~ "wp-admin") {  
        return (pass);
    }

    # Modal POPUP Drupal
    if(req.http.cookie ~ "popup_onload_time") { 
                return(pass);
    }

    #MEDIAWIKI cookies 
        if (req.http.Cookie ~ "(session|UserID|UserName|LoggedOut)" ) {
                return(pass);
        }

    # Pass wordpress-specific cookies
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "wordpress_" || req.http.Cookie ~ "comment_") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Remove the wp-settings-1 cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    # Remove the wp-settings-time-1 cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    # Remove the wp test cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    # Remove the "has_js" cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "has_js=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    # Remove any Google Analytics based cookies
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__utm.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    # Remove Piwik cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_pk_(ses|id)[\.a-z0-9]*)=[^;]*", "");

    if (!(req.url ~ "(user|admin|wp-admin|wp-login)")) {
        #unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    # Check the cookies for wordpress-specific items
    if (!req.http.cookie) {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    # Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "^ *$") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    # Cache the following files extensions
    if (req.url ~ "\.(css|js|png|gif|jp(e)?g|swf|ico)") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    # Drupal fix
    if (req.url ~ "install\.php|update\.php|cron\.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Normalize Accept-Encoding header and compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {

        # Do no compress compressed files...
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
            remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Do not cache HTTP authentication and HTTP Cookie
    if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Cache all others requests
    return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    return (pipe);
}

sub vcl_pass {
    return (pass);
}

# The data on which the hashing will take place
sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }
    # If the client supports compression, keep that in a different cache
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
    }
    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hit {
    # Allow purges
    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_miss {
    # Allow purges
    return (fetch);
}

# This function is used when a request is sent by our backend (Apache server)
sub vcl_fetch {
    # For static content strip all backend cookies
    if (req.url ~ "\.(css|js|png|gif|jp(e?)g)|swf|ico") {
        unset beresp.http.cookie;
    }

    # On enlève les cookies sauf ceux des logins des backoffices 
    if (!(req.url ~ "(mediawiki|flyspray|administrator|installation|user|admin|wp-(login|admin))") && (req.request != "POST") && (beresp.http.x-logged-in == "False")) {    
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie    ;    
    }    

    # Do not cache 403 error pages
    if (beresp.status >= 400) {
        return (hit_for_pass);
    } 

    set beresp.ttl = 1h;
    set beresp.grace = 1d;
    set beresp.http.x-url = req.url;
    set beresp.http.x-host = req.http.host;

    return (deliver);

}

# The routine when we deliver the HTTP request to the user
sub vcl_deliver {

    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "HELL YEAH !";
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "ANOTHER ONE BITES THE DUST";
    }

    # BAN tuto  
    unset resp.http.x-url;
    unset resp.http.x-host;

    # Remove some headers: PHP version
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;

    # Remove some headers: Apache version & OS
    unset resp.http.Server;

    return (deliver);

}

sub vcl_error {
    # If backends sends 500 error, serve cache en check again every minute
    if ( obj.status == 500) {
        set obj.grace = 60s;
        return(restart);
    }
    return (deliver);    
}
```

Oh and BTW if you have any suggestion on how I could better or clean my VCL, you're welcome to tell me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumble on this issue just right now. 
That's pretty simple, yet very stupid from the WP developers. You need to forward the `User-Agent` header in order to trigger browser detection, thus advanced editor support.

```
function user_can_richedit() {
        global $wp_rich_edit, $is_gecko, $is_opera, $is_safari, $is_chrome, $is_IE, $is_edge;
        if ( !isset($wp_rich_edit) ) {
                $wp_rich_edit = false;
                if ( get_user_option( 'rich_editing' ) == 'true' || ! is_user_logged_in() ) { // default to 'true' for logged out users
                        if ( $is_safari ) {
                                 $wp_rich_edit = ! wp_is_mobile() || ( preg_match( '!AppleWebKit/(\d.+)!', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $match ) && intval( $match[1] ) >= 534 );
                        } elseif ( $is_IE ) {
                                 $wp_rich_edit = ( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Trident/7.0;' ) !== false );
                        } elseif ( $is_gecko || $is_chrome || $is_edge || ( $is_opera && !wp_is_mobile() ) ) {
                                $wp_rich_edit = true;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to pass the wp-settings cookies

```
# Pass wordpress-specific cookies
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "(wordpress_|comment_|wp-settings-)") {
    return (pass);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. It still doesn't work though.
I also commentent the following lines, but with no luck :
`set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");`
`set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");`

Answer (score 0):

This issue still exists,

`unset req.http.User-Agent;`

- will cause the same issue. Our fix included reordering the vcl commands and moving the unset User Agent command to only not-logged in users. So logged in users will receive the correct functionality. However this would be dependent on the business requirements and could effect other plugins that operate on the same principles.